# getClientOriginalName on null in laravel

Tags: laravel

I try to insert image file data in database. but it's not working .error message is getClientOriginalName() on null.

My controller is:

```php
public function storeProduct(Request $request) {  
  $ProductImg=$request->file('ProductImg');
  $Name=$ProductImg->getClientOriginalName();
  $uploadPath='public/ProductImg/';
  $ProductImg->move($uploadPath,$Name);
  $imageUrl=$uploadPath.$Name;
  $this->saveProductinfo($request, $imageUrl);
  return redirect('/product/add')->with('message','Product info save Successfully');
}
```

How do I solve this please?

Answer (score 0):

The error states that `$ProductImg` is `null`. That means that the request did not contain a file object. Try `$request->file('ProductImg')->isValid()` to check whether the file has been uploaded. I think you will get a `False` here.

Answer (score 0):

You need check file before it operation

```
if ($request->hasFile('ProductImg')) {
    // your code here
}
```

Important! you need use in you form next attr - enctype="multipart/form-data"

```
<form name="my_form" action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

> enctype="multipart/form-data"

attribute in your form like this.

```
<form name="add_form" action="/add" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```